# React - Getting "Component definition is missing display name" error when using React.memo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, eslint

Why am I getting the ESLint error `Component definition is missing display name` on this code:

```js
export const Button = React.memo(props => {
//...
});
```

Is this a false positive or real error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting an arrow function directly doesn't give the component a `displayName`, but if you export a regular function the function name will be used as `displayName`.

You can also put the function in a variable, set the `displayName` on the function manually, and then export it.

```
const Button = React.memo(props => {
//...
});

Button.displayName = 'Button';
export Button;
```

Comment: Would
`export const Button = React.memo(props => {
//...
});

Button.displayName = 'Button';`

Be OK?

Comment: @lijeles952 Sorry for my typo. Yes, correct. Let me know if it works. I updated my answer as well.